# Youtube API security

Tags: javascript, api

I was playing about with youtube's API yesterday and did some research about its security. Now.. I have a website which I would like to apply Youtube API for it and I just wonder how NON-secure is to display project's API key? I would be using js for that and I mean there is no way I can hide it anyways as everyone who really is looking for it would be able to find via inspect element or just a source code..

Is it enought just to specify a domain name you are using this api key with so no one can use it?

If I am completely wrong please give some information regarding this question.

Comment: Do you need to expose your api  key through client code? Sometimes you can send users' requests through your server, apply the api key and deliver them to YouTube. A kind of proxy put simply. That way the end user will never see the key

Comment: I need to retrieve json information and I can only do it via get function. For example gettinng some videos of a playlist `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=4&key={YOUR_API_KEY}` therefore I will have to use my api key in javascript so everyone will see it

Comment: Is it not enough just to supply domain name for an api? Like I can do for my youtube api -> Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) (Optional)

Comment: Google has good support on their Groups site. They may be able to help you

Comment: One way of doing it is sending your users' requests to your server which rewrites the request with your api key and sends it to YouTube/Google. So that a user request a query which is sent to the server which is sent to google which is returned to the client.

Comment: @Alex yeah thats a good idea. I might do that. but the question is, is it really worth this hassle if that API key cant do any harm?

Comment: As @NeilSmithline said, check what applies with Google on the groups site. But the general idea is that the api key is yours and it should be treated with care. That way no one else can pretend to be you and they won't fill up your quota if there is one.

Comment: Yes, I will check googles forums as well. I know that api key is important somehow, but if I set that this api key ito be used with my websites domain  only, i dont understand what harm can it cause..But anyways..Useful info you two provided, thanks for that!

Comment: Normally an API key is bound to a specific domain. Using it on another website is not working. See here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript They use client IDs which need to be registered. YouTube always had a JavaScript API and provides solutions like OAuth2 and client IDs for authentication.

Comment: How? I never specified to my domain

Comment: Did you create a project in the developers console and got the API key?